# What does this diamond shape represent in this ER diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd

[image]

And what is testlog in this diagram is it attribute on relationship.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram):

> The UML representation of a composition relationship shows composition as a filled diamond shape on the containing class end of the lines that connect contained class(es) to the containing class.

In other words, a `patient` can have any number of `account`s associated with (possessed by) it.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio